# Match if date is within date range google sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two columns with a start (column `B`) and end (column `C`) date range, and a cell (`G1`) with a date.
I want to be able to look at columns `B` and `C` and return true if `G1` falls in between any of the date range of `B` and `C`, and if `G1` is not within the date, return false.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following formula

```
=IFERROR(IF( 
     QUERY(L2:M14,"WHERE L <= DATE '"&TEXT(K2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
                     AND M >= DATE '"&TEXT(K2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'") 
                              >0,TRUE),FALSE)
```

[image]

*(Please adjust ranges to your needs)*

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this formula is used on row 2, this will work:

```
=ISBETWEEN($G$1,$B2,$C2)
```

Change `$B2` and `$C2` appropriately if you're not on row 2.

Note that the `ISBETWEEN()` function has two additional optional boolean parameters to control whether the start/end dates are inclusive or exclusive for the range; both default to `TRUE` for inclusive endpoints.